# Is it a good way to make a JSON Request?

Tags: python, json

```
import simplejson as json
import requests

[...]

def __init__(self, id):
     req = requests.get('http://api.example/%i?api_key=foo' % id)
     data = json.loads(req.content)
     self.name = data['name']

[...]
```

Is there a better way or is it a good one? It works, but I don't know if it's a good aproach or not.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. Better how? One tip though, you can do `req.json()` rather than passing the content to json.loads.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about, a way to make the code more simple, something like that.

Comment: You can also pass `params={'api_key': 'foo'}` instead of directly setting it in the url.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: notice that OP uses `simplejson` that might differ (time performance, bugs) from stdlib `json` module. I don't know what module `req.json()` would use. Also `json.loads(req.content)` assumes `req.content` is in utf-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you do json.loads() or req.json(), I would write my function as below to handle the
cases when req.content is not a valid JSON such as in the case of a 404 or 500.

```
import simplejson as json
import requests

def jsonize(req):
     try:
         data = json.loads(req.content)
     except json.JsonDecodeError:
         data = {'error': req.status_code}
     except Exception:
         data = {}
     return data

def __init__(self, id):
     req = requests.get('http://api.example/%i?api_key=foo' % id)
     data = jsonize(req)
     if data and not 'error' in data:
         self.name = data.get('name', "")
```